# Convert Rx Observable to writable stream

Tags: .net, stream, system.reactive

I see that Reactive Extension's `Observable<T>` has very similar semantics compared to ordinary `System.IO.Stream` is there a way to convert Observable to **writable** Stream? I.e. I want to generate data using Reactive Extensions and feed that data to native Stream, is there a short path to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're wanting to subscribe to an observable to write its content to a stream? It's really kind of basic with the `.Create` method. Can you provide a source observable and a sample output file so that an answer can be put together?

Comment: I would like to create a stream from observable, eventually I've approached this problem from another side

Comment: Can you provide a source observable and a sample output file so that an answer can be put together?